# a difference quotient question

Tags: functions

[image]

Regarding the part marked in green: How does f(x+h) become 5(x+h)

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial.
Let y = x+h 
Then what is f(y)?

Answer (score 2):

Recall function notation.  If $f(x)=5x$, then $f(something)=5\cdot(something)$.  Now let $something$ be $(x+h)$.

Answer (score 1):

In words, $f$ is the function that takes a real number $x$ as input and returns the real number $5x$ as output:  *it just multiplies the input by five.*

If the input happens to be the expression $x + h$ (a sum of two numbers, which is another number, after all), then the output is $5$ times that expression, namely
$$
5(x + h).
$$